# ArangoDB-NET Error: System.Net.WebException: 'No such host is known No such host is known'

Tags: c#, .net, arangodb

I'm working on a project that needed a `Graph DB`. I'm developing the project using `C# .Net Core`. I had to choose `ArangoDB` as a `Graph DB` for this project. Unfortunately, there is no official driver for `.Net`. That's why I choose a community driver. That is `ArangoDB-NET`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/ArangoDB-NET/

https://github.com/yojimbo87/ArangoDB-NET

The driver is working fine with **my local installed** `ArangoDB` database. The driver is returning an error when I'm trying to deploy the database in **`ArangoDB Cloud (ArangoDB Oasis)`**.

> Error: System.Net.WebException: 'No such host is known No such host is
> known'

[image]

Please check the below information about the database connection:

**Connection String Settings:**

```
  "DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionName": "CloudDBConnection",
    "Host": "https://xxxxxxxx.arangodb.cloud",
    "Port": 8529,
    "UserName": "root",
    "Password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "DatabaseName": "KKBDTestDB"
  }
```

**Database Connection:**

```
private readonly ADatabase db;
public DatabseService(IDatabaseSettings settings)
{
    ASettings.AddConnection(settings.ConnectionName, settings.Host, settings.Port, false, settings.DatabaseName, settings.UserName, settings.Password, true);
    db = new ADatabase(settings.ConnectionName);
}
```

Comment: is dns able to resolve the host

Comment: yes, it is. I can access the database using the host and the port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Remove https from your host name, then try.**

Connection string should be:

```
"DatabaseSettings": {
    "ConnectionName": "CloudDBConnection",
    "Host": "xxxxxxxx.arangodb.cloud",
    "Port": 8529,
    "UserName": "root",
    "Password": "xxxxxxxx",
    "DatabaseName": "KKBDTestDB"
  }
```

**2) Download public key for windows  from arongodb cloud and follow
the following steps:**

1. Convert Certificate (PEM) to ca-9676da18.crt
2. Open a Powershell with Run as Administrator
3. certutil -addstore root ca-9676da18.crt